# Visual mode mapping not working. Do I have to escape characters?

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following dysfunctional mapping

```
" Capitalise each word in selection
vmap gw :'<,'>s/\<./\u&/g<CR>
```

which should do what the comment says. But when I use it, vim reports `E488: Trailing characters`. It works when I leave out the selection marks `'<,'>`, but then it applies to the whole line.

I suspect I need to escape something here, but [the help page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)) only lists some other characters which must be escaped.

Comment: I think you can also capitalise from visual mode with the mapping `gU`.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I do not want to capitalise each character, merely the first one in each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter command-line mode from visual mode Vim automatically populates the command-line with `'<,'>`. Your mapping adds another `'<,'>` after the automatic one which makes your command invalid.

This:

```
xnoremap gw :s/\<./\u&/g<CR>
```

does exactly what you'd expect.

--- edit ---

Substitutions are line-wise by default. If you want to restrict your substitution to the current visual selection you need to add the `\%V` atom to your search pattern:

```
xnoremap gw :s/\%V\<./\u&/g<CR>
```

See `:help \%V`.

Comment: For me, it capitalises each word in the line my selection is on. So, everything inside the selection is processed, but also stuff before and after.

Comment: Yes of course. What did you expect? Substitutions are line-wise by default. See my edit.

Comment: I did not realise that. Thanks for clearing that up.